# How to enable default actions for update password in keycloak with kcadm?

Tags: keycloak

I need to enable update password under default actions in keycloak with kcadm, can one help in achieving this !!!

I want to do this as part of my realm creation

[image: How do I enable default actions for update password with kcadm in keycloak]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a specific admin cli command to do that.

But, you can achieve this by using the resource uri :

```
./kcadm.sh update /authentication/required-actions/UPDATE_PASSWORD \
-s alias=UPDATE_PASSWORD \
-s defaultAction=true \
-s enabled=true \
-s name="Update Password" \
-s priority=30 \
-s providerId=UPDATE_PASSWORD \
-r <REPLACE_BY_REALM_IF_NEEDED>
```

More info here : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#basic-operations-and-resource-uris